# Toggle many classes

Tags: javascript, toggle

so thanks for you all that help me. You made me think what i was doing, so i short my code in what i thought would be good, but before the code was long but working now, short but not works with the first panel even that there is no errors.So maybe a loop?
So the html goes like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="down sound">
       <img id="batman" class="image-1-panel active" src="flash.svg">
       <img class="image-2-panel notactive" src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/3c096341-2a6c-4ae6-bb76-3973445cfbcf/6b938520-4962-403a-9ce3-7bf298918cad.jpg">
       <p class="image-3-panel notactive">Bane</p>
       <p>Joker</p>
       <p>Alfred</p>
   </div>
```

And then it repeats for 3 more containers like that one. On css for the active and not active i have:

```
.notactive{
      visibility: hidden;
      position: relative;
  }

  .active{
      position: absolute;

  }
```

And in js:

```
document.querySelector('#batman').addEventListener('click', batman);
function batman(){
    document.querySelector('.image-1-panel').classList.toggle('.notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-1-panel').classList.toggle('.active');
    document.querySelector('.image-2-panel').classList.toggle('.active');
    document.querySelector('.image-2-panel').classList.toggle('.notactive');
}
```

But nothing happens... I also have a for loop for sounds that is working still good, but the panels don´t move. Can someone share some light here? I thought in a loop and try it following the function but also didn´t work so clearly I am missing something, maybe wrong element I am trying to catch?
Above i have my question without the edit where you can understand what i mean.
Thanks for your help

I have 4 panels. In each panel, there will be 3 images/text one beyond the other. So it will work that when I press panel 1, panel 2,3 and 4 will turn to show an image. Press panel 2, and panel 1,3 and 4 will turn to show different image then when pressed the panel one. And so one for the rest of the panels.
So i start and i create a function for the first panel. It works, but there is any way i can make it simple? Here is the code:

```
function guessWho(){
    document.querySelector('.image-1-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-2-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-2-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-3-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-3-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-4-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-4-panel').classList.toggle('notactive1');
    document.querySelector('.image-5-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-5-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-6-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-6-panel').classList.toggle('notactive2');
    document.querySelector('.image-7-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-7-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-8-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-8-panel').classList.toggle('notactive3');
}
```

Any way I can put this simple? I don´t want to use any framework, so it has to be pure js. Thank you

Comment: you don't have any common classes on them then its you need to loop with them

Comment: Some of your toggles are `notactive1`, `notactive2`, etc. Is there a pattern for which ones have a number at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    document.querySelector(`.image-${i}-panel`).classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector(`.image-${i}-panel`).classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that querySelector takes a string, you could build that string up inside of a loop and use the iterator inside of the string.  Something like

```
for(i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.image-' + i + '-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
}
```

would toggle the 'notactive' class for everything that has image-x-panel.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    document.querySelector(`.image-${i}-panel`).classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector(`.image-${i}-panel`).classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Solution 2

Add some CSS class to your HTML like `CLASSNAME`

And use try this

```
document.querySelector(`CLASSNAME`).classList.toggle('notactive');
document.querySelector(`CLASSNAME`).classList.toggle('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the new states you want your classes to be modified by.  In this case, you have an object that looks like this:
    {a:false,i:""}

where a is whether it's active, and i is your post class increment, like "notactive2".

Then you create a nested loop where you iterate over each number twice, and check the position in your list of states to determine what things will be added to your base "active" class.

```js
 var activeClassesList = [{a:false,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:"1"},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:"2"},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:""},{a:true,i:""},{a:false,i:"3"}];

var imageClassPrefix = ".image-";
var imageClassPostfix = "-panel";
var start =1;
var base = 8;
for (var i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
   var count = 1;
   for (var j=start;j<(start+base);j++) {

      var modifier = activeClassesList[j-1];
      var cls = (modifier.a ? "" : "not") + "active" + modifier.i;
      document.querySelector(imageClassPrefix + String(count) +  imageClassPostfix).classList.toggle(cls);
      count++;

   }
   start = start + base;
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to just focus on the results, so we can remove the first selectors for each image panel since they are immediately being overwritten.

That leaves the second queries for each selector.  This can be simplified by combining multiple selectors inside a queryselectorAll for items with the same class being toggled.

```js
function guessWho(){

    document.querySelector('.image-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.image-2-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelectorAll('.image-3-panel, .image-5-panel, .image-7-panel, .image-7-panel').forEach((f)=>{f.classList.toggle('notactive');})
    document.querySelector('.image-4-panel').classList.toggle('notactive1');
    document.querySelector('.image-6-panel').classList.toggle('notactive2');
}

guessWho();
```

```css
.allpanels > div {display: inline-block;border:solid 1px black;height:50px;width:50px;margin:8px;}
.active { background-color:red;}
.notactive { background-color:lightsteelblue;}
.notactive1 { background-color:green;}
.notactive2 { background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<div class="allpanels">
<div class="image-1-panel">1</div>
<div class="image-2-panel">2</div>
<div class="image-3-panel">3</div>
<div class="image-4-panel">4</div>
<div class="image-5-panel">5</div>
<div class="image-6-panel">6</div>
<div class="image-7-panel">7</div>
</div>
```